# Ideal operational amplifier resistor question

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors

My question is: since the same current flows through R1 and R2 the input current is 0, so can we treat them as resistors in series and add them together? If yes, what would be the expressions in terms of Ohm's law?

Example of the situation:

[image]

Comment: If current I = 0, then it is still 0...

Comment: Yes. The OP amp current input is 0. My question is, can we add R1 and R2 and treat them as series? Because the currently only flows through them.

Comment: And if so, what would the expression be? (U-Uinput)=(R1+R2)*I?

Comment: No, you cannot treat them as a single resistor. Because of the "virtual ground" at the (-) input. For ideal inverting amplifier V(-)= V(+)   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbMnQdRzD8A&t=6s

Comment: Yes, indeed. I know the ideal amplifiers properties. Thanks for clarifying. I was taught that if currents are in the same in two resistors, I can add them together. Which is not the case here as of the node voltage in the (-) input. Correct?

Comment: Yes, the opamp "action" via R2 feedback resistor forced the voltage at the (-) node equal to 0V. So IR1 current is simply equal to IR1 = Vin/R1 and IR2 = (0V - Vout)/R2 and this two current must be equal  (Vin - 0V)/R1 = (0V - Vout)/R2 hence Vout/Vin = -R2/R1

Comment: Resistors are not in series if there’s something else connected to their junction; and there is - the op amp inverting input. And that connection is not benign, it drags the junction to the same voltage as the non-inverting input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can (you must) consider both resistors in series if you are applying the superposition rule for calculating the closed-loop gain.

Based on the assumption that the inverting opamp input has a potential Vn=0 , we have a simple voltage divider consisting of the series R1 and R2:

- Vn1=Vin[R2/(R1+R2)] setting Vout=0,
- Vn2=Vout[R1/(R1+R2)]  setting Vin=0.
- Vn=Vn1+Vn2=0  >>>>  Vout/Vin=-R2/R1.

Comment: Note that the voltage divider rule was derived/formulated using Ohms law and the assumption that the current through R1 and R2 is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I could use the superposition analysis, yes. But what I ultimately wanted was a faster way to achieve the output voltage. What i initially did to solve: Is to find the current (I) over R1 using Ohms Law. I = (U1-Vn)/R1, and further apply KVL at the node Vn to Vout. Vout = Vn + I*R2. To find the output voltage, now this way isn't the worse. Could also do: (U1-Vn)/R1 = (Vn-Vout)/R2 and solve for Vout. But is there a faster way to achieve this? As they are in series, indeed. But without using the superposition theorem, which I can also use yes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding up the two resistors yields nothing useful.  These resistor are in series, but the junction between them is being held at whatever voltage the positive input to the opamp is at.

The same current does flow thru them.  That means that the ratio of voltages across one relative to the other is the same as its resistance relative to the other.  This is the useful property exploited by the common inverting amplifier you show.  The gain is simply -R2/R1.  The sum R1+R2 doesn't tell you much.